# EditText boxes look differently onFocus event

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, styling

Hi I have a couple of `EditText` boxes in a `GridLayout`. However, the code for the `EditText` is exactly the same. But they look different `onFocus` event. Any idea why this is occurring?

The texboxes after each one of them were selected: 
[image: Different Styles]

```
    <GridLayout         
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDisinfectionContact"
                style="@style/formsubsubheader"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/disinfection_contact" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPpmUnit"
                style="@style/fieldlabel"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/unit_ppm" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMinutesUnits"
                style="@style/fieldlabel"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/unit_mins" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLvlCheAdd"
                style="@style/fieldlabel"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:labelFor="@+id/etLvlCheAddPpm"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"

                android:text="@string/lvl_cheaddition" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etLvlCheAddPpm"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:ems="16"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="50"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etLvlCheAddMinutes"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:ems="16"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="50" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLvlFlushADD"
                style="@style/fieldlabel"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:labelFor="@+id/etLvlFlushAddPpm"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"

                android:text="@string/lvl_flushddition" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etLvlFlushAddPpm"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:ems="16"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="50" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etLvlFlushMinutes"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:ems="16"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="50" />

        </GridLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your `GridLayout` xml and also the `EditText` ?

Comment: @Derek added ..

Comment: post your focus event also

Comment: yep it was onFocus event that was causing it...

Answer (score 0):

On Android O there has been some [Input and Navigation Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#ian) . You won't see the changes in the `View` on different android versions. You can check if your app is running on O, and if so call `setDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled(false)` on the `EditText` view.

This sets whether this `View` should use a default focus highlight when it gets focused but doesn't have `R.attr.state_focused` defined in its background.

Comment: API min is 26 fro this method my project is 19